# Alert doesn't fire on Windows Phone 7 emulator using JavaScript and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova, alert

I've tried to fire an alert on document.ready in a JavaScript file but the alert didn't fire when testing on Windows Phone 7 emulator.
btw I uses PhoneGap 2.2.0, JS, and HTML
here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    alert("Hello World WP7");
    initPlateImage();
});
```

also I've tried

```
window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;
```

and

```
navigator.notification.alert("Hi");
```

but no use, Any suggestions
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Cordova is not initialized at the time you call alert(). Try the following way - "deviceready" is an Cordova specific event telling you that Cordova is successfully initialized

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady()
    {
    // IE does NOT provide an alert method, you can patch it with this line after deviceready.
    window.alert = window.alert || navigator.notification.alert;

    alert("Hello World WP7");


    }
```